# input string was not in a correct format c# datetimepicker

Tags: c#, mysql, string, datetimepicker

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_action == "edit")
                {
                    update(_id, int.Parse(cbSupplier.ValueMember), dtpTRXdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dtpDUEdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtRemarks.Text.ToString(), _conn);
                }
                else
                {
                    insert(int.Parse(cbSupplier.ValueMember), dtpTRXdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dtpDUEdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtRemarks.Text.ToString(), _conn);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
       }

public void insert(int sup_ID, string TRX_date, string DUE_date, string remarks, MySqlConnection conn)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sup_ID.ToString() + " " + TRX_date + " " + DUE_date + " " + remarks);

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PO_HEADER VALUES(null," + sup_ID + ",'" + TRX_date + "','" + DUE_date + "','" + remarks + "')";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

public void update(int id, int sup_id, string trx_date, string due_date, string remarks, MySqlConnection conn)
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE PO_HEADER SET SUPPLIER_ID=" + sup_id + ", TRX_DATE='" + trx_date + "', DUE_DATE='" + due_date + "', REMARKS='" + remarks + "' WHERE ID=" + id;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

dtpTRXdate it's datetimepicker
the problem at : dtpTRXdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") and dtpDUEdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
when i click button save and run the function, it say "input string was not in a correct format"
i messagebox the string it's true, example : "2012-12-12"
have any idea???

Comment: You shouldn't use message boxes for debugging. Learn to use the built-in debugger instead and you'll have a much better time of finding problems like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are sending the `Date` value selected from `DateTimePicker` control after converting into `string` as `yyyy-MM-dd`, but in `database` table the `datatype` might be `Date` so it takes `Date and Time` both.

**Solution :**  you need to convert `Date` Selected from `DateTimePicker` control into  into `Date and Time` instead of converting into `Date` only.

Try This:

```
dtpTRXdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

**Suggestion :** by using `parameterised queries` you do not need to worry about the `types` being passed as it will be taken care by default.

by using `parameterised queries` you can avoid [SQL Injection Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

**Complete Code:**  using `parameterised queries`

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_action == "edit")
            {
                update(_id, int.Parse(cbSupplier.ValueMember), dtpTRXdate.Value, dtpDUEdate.Value, txtRemarks.Text.ToString(), _conn);
            }
            else
            {
                insert(int.Parse(cbSupplier.ValueMember), dtpTRXdate.Value, dtpDUEdate.Value, txtRemarks.Text.ToString(), _conn);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
   }

public void insert(int sup_ID, DateTime TRX_date, DateTime DUE_date, string remarks, MySqlConnection conn)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sup_ID.ToString() + " " + TRX_date.ToShortDateSTring() + " " + DUE_date.ToShortDateSTring() + " " + remarks);

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PO_HEADER VALUES(@value1,@sup_ID,@TRX_date,@ DUE_date,@remarks)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1",DBNull.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup_ID",sup_ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRX_date",TRX_date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DUE_date",DUE_date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks",remarks);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

public void update(int id, int sup_id, string trx_date, string due_date, string remarks, MySqlConnection conn)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE PO_HEADER SET SUPPLIER_ID=@sup_id,TRX_DATE=@trx_date,DUE_DATE=@due_date,REMARKS=@remarks WHERE ID=@id";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup_ID",sup_ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trx_date",trx_date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due_date",due_date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks",remarks);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup_ID",id);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```